Ensuring at least one required field in a TypedDict in Python
Giving the following code:
from typing_extensions import NotRequired, TypedDict, Unpack

class LoginParams(TypedDict):
    url: NotRequired[str]
    username: NotRequired[str]
    password: NotRequired[str]
    api_key: NotRequired[str]

def do_login(**kwargs: Unpack[LoginParams]):
    pass

How can I ensure that at least one of the LoginParams fields is required, no matter which one? In other words, an instance of LoginParams should not be empty. If this is not possible using TypedDict, what other approach can I take?

Are you only interested in a TypedDict with at least one field? If yes, then there is this duplicate. Or do you also need the do_login function to accept at least one argument?

Does this help?

If do_login return value is usable, solution by @dROOOze is the perfect one (minimal repetition, and Never will almost always result in a type error/unreachable warning wherever it's used). If it returns None, that's kind of a problem (def fn() -> None: do_login() will pass cleanly even in strict mode and with all warnings enabled, you can forget about this case only if do_login returns a value that should be used somehow later on). In the latter case, solution in the dupe from @Wombatz comment is your best bet - a union of all non-empty variants (consider mypy plugin if it's common)
